# How to connect Sunspot to remote solr server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, remote-access, sunspot

I'm setting up a remote Solr connection just to test it and my config file only refers to the remote server, but when I run

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

it starts a local instance of Solr.

I've tried changing everything in my `sunspot.yml` to refer to the remote server and when I go into the application and try to search, it does use the remote server, but I'd like to be able to run Sunspot commands on it because reindexing without Sunspot is a pain.

This is my `sunspot.yml` file:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: {remote host}
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: {remote host}
    port: 8983
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: {remote host}
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

There are no error messages, but I would expect Sunspot commands run on the application server to affect the remote Solr server.

When I run:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

it says it's

```
Starting Solr on port 8983 from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3.2/gems/sunspot_solr-2.3.0/solr/server
```

but that should be the remote connection.

Does anyone have any ideas how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, it was with my solr cores. If you're having a similar problem, make sure to set up a core before you try to connect, otherwise solr won't have anything to work off of.